# Core Data - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying in swift in iOS to retrieve data elements of my xcdatamodel
 file

take a look at:

```
@IBAction func sees(_ sender: Any) {
    let appdel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let contect:NSManagedObjectContext = appdel.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var results = NSManagedObject()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Places")
    let records = try! contect.execute(fetchRequest)
    let getlatitude = records.value(forKey: "lat")
    let getlongitude = records.value(forKey: "long")
    print("getted: \(getlatitude) \(getlongitude)")
}
```

how look my xcdatamodel file

[image]

And i have a crash with:

> 2017-02-08 14:10:21.330293 Parkar[6398:1283817] [LogMessageLogging]
>   6.1 Unable to retrieve CarrierName. CTError: domain-2, code-5, errStr:((os/kern) failure) 2017-02-08 14:10:24.404130
>   Parkar[6398:1283769] [error] error: CoreData: error: Failed to call
>   designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'NSManagedObject'
>   CoreData: error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated
>   initializer on NSManagedObject class 'NSManagedObject'
>
> 2017-02-08 14:10:24.410434 Parkar[6398:1283769] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lat.'

Comment: try records[0].value(forKey: "lat") as! Float

Comment: No I can't compile it because at the right of Xcode i have "Type NSPersistentStoreResut has no subscript members"

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code,it worked for me

```
  let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
        // Create Entity Description
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Places", in: self.managedObjectContext)

        // Configure Fetch Request
        fetch.entity = entityDescription

        do {
            let result = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetch)
            var orderList :NSArray  = result
             let lat = orderList.value(forKey: "lat") as! String
              let long = orderList.value(forKey: "long") as! String

        } catch {
            let fetchError = error as NSError
            print(fetchError)
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution I managed to put together:

```
let appdel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appdel.persistentContainer.viewContext
var results = NSManagedObject() //not sure what this is used for
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Places")

do {

    let records = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Places]

    let placeObject = records[0]

    let lat = placeObject.lat

    let long = placeObject.long

    print("\(lat) \(long)")

 } catch {

    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

first off, I changed `contect` to the correct word `context`. Next we have to surround our `try` statement with a `catch` to catch any errors. Then I casted the `records` variable to an array of `Places` from your Entity in Core Data. Now you are able to access attributes from the `Places` Entity such as the `lat` and `long`.